# Github pages not updating home page

Tags: jekyll, cache-control, octopress, github-pages

On my octopress/jekyll blog http://www.railsonmaui.com, after I update an article and push to GitHub pages, the specific blog article is updating, but the home page of blog articles is not updating.

Is there any way to tell GitHub pages to clear the cache on the home page?
Any reason the home page is the only page that has this issue?

Comment: I was seeing this same issue while running the local Compass server, started with "rake preview". Strangely enough, restarting the server seemed to fix the issue both locally and remotely.

Comment: Recently, no issues! I'm guessing github fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and found that stopping the Jekyll server

```
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop
```

and starting it again

```
jekyll serve
```

refreshed my home page

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your code to octopress v3 and now you have the `rake deploy` which will build, update & deploy your code to github.

You will have to set it up with:

```
rake setup_github_pages

# Build and deploy the blog to github
rake deploy
```

Once using this task you site will be updated with the latest code.

Answer (score -1):

did you run `jekyll build` after updating?